# Targeting x86 from ARM?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

Is it possible to compile to x86 using gcc on an ARM machine? I can't find any `-march` option which would allow this to be done.. if it can't be done, no big deal, but I'm still interested to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you don't want a -march machine.  You want to build or install a cross compiler with arm as the host architecture and x86 as the target architecture.
Typically (assuming a linux os) you might get binaries like x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc for the compiler and x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ for the C++ compiler.

Building Gcc cross compilers is a bit of an art, but the gcc documentation is reasonably good.

Answer (score -3):

No. Its because cross compiler(including clang) can generate binaries from host gcc for a target. There is no compiler which can generate x86 instructions from arm.

Comment: You make no sense, compilation has nothing to do with host architecture. It only depends on availability of library, headers and compiler support for target's architecture.