# Is it possible to develop a Stack Buffer Overflow exploit compiled on x86 on ARM architecture?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I have an M1 processor and parallels. Is it possible to develop Buffer Overflow exploits for vulnerable applications running on x86 given my processor is ARM?

If I cross-compile the vulnerable application on my ARM processor, the exploit development process and subsequent exploit will be as if I was on x86 etc? i.e. all the addresses in assembly would be agnostic of the processor architecture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting x86 from ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436084/targeting-x86-from-arm)

Comment: Certainly helpful; I'm looking for a little bit more than cross-compilation. Thank you.

Comment: What are you looking for then? How to develop the buffer overflow itself?

Comment: No. Maybe expanding on the link you posted; if I cross-compile the vulnerable application on my ARM processor, the exploit development process and subsequent exploit will be as if I was on x86 etc? i.e. all the addresses in assembly would be agnostic of the processor architecture?

Comment: I think you should edit and add this clarification to your question. No, the addresses will not be the same since each architecture has a different memory layout.